# Saving image using Qt: "Device not writable" error

Tags: image, qt, save

I am trying to write a function, that saves a QImage object on a hard drive as image-type file. Here's the code of the function:

```
void ImageMaster::saveImage()
{
    QStringList mimeTypeFilters;
    foreach (const QByteArray &mimeTypeName, QImageWriter::supportedMimeTypes()) {
        mimeTypeFilters.append(mimeTypeName);
    }
    mimeTypeFilters.sort();
    const QStringList picturesLocations = QStandardPaths::standardLocations(QStandardPaths::PicturesLocation);
    QFileDialog dialog(this, tr("Save Image"),
                       picturesLocations.isEmpty() ? QDir::currentPath() : picturesLocations.last());
    dialog.setAcceptMode(QFileDialog::AcceptSave);
    dialog.setMimeTypeFilters(mimeTypeFilters);
    dialog.selectMimeTypeFilter("image/png");
    if (dialog.exec() == QDialog::Accepted) {
        qDebug() << "accepted!";
        const QString& fileName = dialog.selectedFiles().first();
        qDebug() << fileName;
        QImageWriter writer;
        writer.setFormat("png");
        writer.setDevice(new QFile(fileName));
        writer.setFileName(fileName);
        if (!writer.write(getCurrentImage())) {
            qDebug() << writer.errorString();
        }
    }
    else {
        qDebug() << "not accepted!";
    }
}
```

And here's the output when I try to save image previously loaded into my program from the hard drive:

```
accepted!
"C:/Users/toshiba/Pictures/im.png"
QFSFileEngine::open: No file name specified
QFile::remove: Empty or null file name
"Device not writable"
```

What do I do wrong? The `getCurrentImage` method returns a perfectly looking when displayed QImage object.

Comment: You didn't `open` your file. And you're leaking the `QFile` object. How about just using `getCurrentImage().save(fileName)` ?

Comment: Why are you setting both device and file name? Please read the documentation of both methods. Looks like you are creating the same file twice.

Comment: @peppe, did it. The same output

Comment: @hyde, initially I set only file name and I got this error. Because of the "Device not writable" message I tried to set a device. And instead of, as you say, being created twice, file is not created at all.

Comment: Hmm, try using QFileInfo on the path returned by the dialog. And try saving to that file from... *paint* maybe.  Just to verify the path is ok.